# How do I 'href' bootstrap3 directory when I use django 1.8 framework?

Tags: html, django, twitter-bootstrap, web-frameworks

This is what my project directory looks like (significantly truncated to get to my point quickly):

```
├── bootstrap-3.3.5-dist
└── mysite
    ├── db.sqlite3
    ├── myApp
    │   ├── admin.py
    │   ├── forms.py
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── templates
    │   │   └── myApp
    │   │       ├── base.html
    │   │       ├── index.html
    │   ├── tests.py
    │   ├── urls.py
    │   └── views.py
```

I want to apply bootstrap style to `mysite/templates/myApp/base.html`, which is what I have below (only the section that has the href):

```
<head><link href="/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"></head>
<body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

So, I have tried to add various number of `../` in front of `/css` and `/js`, none of which worked. Can anyone tell me how I can apply my bootstrap css style to these html files when they are not at the same directory?

Comment: Just to clarify: `/css/bootstrap.min.css` lives somewhere inside `bootstrap-3.3.5-dist/`? Also, are you using [Bower](http://bower.io) or anything?

Comment: @mfcovington Yes, these two .css live inside bootstrap directory. I didn't use Bower, I just downloaded the directory down (the easiest option).

Comment: As far as I know, you can't do what you are asking. I think your options are: serve your static files with a different server, use a CDN, manually place the files in a static dir, or use something like Bower to do it for you. If someone else knows a way, I'd be happy to hear of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You currently have bootstrap in a non-web accessible location.

While you could extract the contents of bootstrap-3.3.5-dist/ to your Django project in static files, and reference it that way, there's a very easy to use Django app for using bootstrap3. You can find it here:

https://github.com/dyve/django-bootstrap3

You can install it with this command, and and it to your installed apps:

```
pip install django-bootstrap3
```

See the link for more details.

Comment: The documentation is extremely simplified, I can't understand what's going on at all. I feel this package has significantly reduced the functionality of bootstrap... How do I still use all css style feature of bootstrap using this package?